# Footer issue: Text left, text right, image right, everything inline and collinear not working

Tags: html, css, footer

I have been trying to create a new footer for my website that looks like this:
[footer_nice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjqmb.png)

Unfortunately, I have only been able to recreate that in gimp, and not in html & css.
So far, I have been only partially successful. I have been able to align all the text and image so they are all collinear and inline, like this:
[footer_bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNDKq.png)

However, they are not separated into a left and a right. Whenever I try to float left or text-align right, or other combinations using divs and spans, it ends up breaking the inline property and the images and text are no longer collinear.
I have been able to seperate the text into left and right using seperate divs and spans, but only when they are not collinear, which is a bit of a bummer.

Here is my HTMl & CSS:

```css
/* footer */
.middle > * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

footer {
 color: #666;    
   font-size: 1.4em;
 background: #191919;
 border-top: 1px solid #444;
 padding: 20px;   
 white-space: nowrap;
}

footer a {
 color: #888;    
 display:inline-block;

}   
footer a:hover {color: #BBB;}
footer img {
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 4px; 
}
```

```html
<footer> 
 &copy; <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script><a href="index.html">&nbsp;WEBSITE</a>
 BUILT WITH <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">CSS</a> &amp; <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">HTML</a>. OPTIMIZED.<span class="middle"><a href="url"><img src="https://placebear.com/32/25"/></a></span>
</footer>
```

Is there something I am missing? Is it some simple css that I am just forgetting? Any input would be fantastic. I hope this does not come across as a stupid question. I looked around a bit on here and w3schools and could not come to a conclusion. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your HTML:

`<div class="float-right>` class containing your text & img that goes on the right

To your CSS:
`float:right` to your `footer img`

and

`.float-right {float:right;}`

Note that it may have responsive issues when viewed on mobile, but it's a quick-fix for desktop sized.

Do not forget to `clear` your floating elements after.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your suggestions, but the image is slightly off center from the center line of the text. It does successfully accomplish the left and right portions of the footer though, which is a step forward. I added a clear:both in my html, but forgot to add it above.

Comment: Try adjusting your image padding in that case, since they are all set at 0 except for the left at 4px.

Comment: Thanks. I added 4px padding to the bottom of the image and that seemed to bring the image to the centerline of the floated right text. On closer inspection I noticed that the left and right text are not aligned and are slightly off centerline, even before I added the extra bottom padding to the image. These are the same issues I had when I tried to add seperate divs and use ID selectors on portions of text within the same div. :/

Comment: You would have to then adjust the padding and margin of your divs and text elements to create your desired look.

Answer (score 0):

I troubleshooted some more. this is another potential solution, but the right side overflows and doesn't stay bounded to the right side of the footer.

```css
.middle > * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eee;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  width:100%;
  text-align: right;
}

footer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
footer a{
  display: inline-block;
  
}
```

```html
 <footer> 
      &copy; <script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script><a href="index.html">&nbsp;WEBSITE</a>
   <div class="float-right">BUILT WITH <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer">CSS</a> &amp; <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer">HTML</a>. OPTIMIZED <span class="middle"><a href="https://developers.google.com/"><img src="https://placebear.com/32/25"/></a></span>
   </div>
  <div class="clearer"></div>
  </footer>
```

I was not able to resolve the overflow issue with this particular solution, but as I was working on it I thought of a fix for the collinear issue with the solution offered by BrainHappy. If I add a dummy image to the left side of the footer which is the same height as the image on the right side of the footer, this would resolve the collinear alignment problem of the text and the image. This dummy image would be the same color as the background of course. depending on placement, you could adjust the padding to compensate for the presence of this dummy photo. example:
[derp_fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gC6QH.png)

This solution works, but it is far from elegant. I feel dummy images are bad practice, so I may forgo images in the footer altogether. If anyone else has any other suggestions I am all ears. Thanks!